# how can i unload and clear interval function, when the dropdown option unselected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an option in my HTML file like this

```
 <select class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
                <option value="Batt-1" data-show=".Batt-1">Batt-1</option>
                <option value="Batt-2" data-show=".Batt-2">Batt-2</option>
                <option value="Batt-3" data-show=".Batt-3">Batt-3</option>
</select>
```

and when selecting an option, I run a jquery to show a div and run a function to load a PHP file. this is the Jquery code

```
  $(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function() {
            var target = $(this).data('target');
            var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
            if (show == ".Batt-1") {
                var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                    $('#responsecontainer').load('./utils/data.php');
                }, 1000);
            }
            if (show == ".Batt-2") {
                var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                    $('#responsecontainer2').load('./utils/data-2.php');
                }, 1000);
            }
            $(target).children().addClass('hide');
            $(show).removeClass('hide');
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
        });
```

so, my question is, how can I stop the interval and unload the PHP docs when I change the selected option?

Comment: what I understand from your question is you want to populate dropdown every time with new values using php api call on dropdown value change, and from your code it seems that it's working fine, but what actual issue you're facing? you're asking solution directly without elaborating your problem.

Comment: thx for your insight @WaqasHafeez.  so sorry, because I confuse how to describe it, I recorded the result from the code above on my screen and upload the video. this is the link to the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L-T5VM2HVB5tUCMAb5a-3e0rBEUzO837/view?usp=sharing.